# Spring Boot application cannot run in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am building a Spring Boot application for providing some REST services and I'd like to import it in Docker. If I run my application within IntelliJ pressing the run button, I can load the endpoints correctly.

My app is listening on the port 8091, as my dockerfile is the following

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD out/artifacts/web_services_main_jar/web_services.main.jar lib_image.jar
EXPOSE 8091
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","lib_image.jar"]
```

The code for building and running the docker container is the following

```
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=out/artifacts/web_services_main_jar/web_services.main.jar -t lib_proj .

docker run -p 8090:8091 lib_proj
```

The problem is that when the application is running in docker and I try to load "localhost:8090/user" in a browser, chrome returns the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE message.

If I open Docker and open the CLI of the container and I run

```
curl localhost:8091/user
```

even here an error is printed "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8091: Connection refused". Any suggestion?

EDIT: my application.properties already specifies address and port as follows:

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=8091
```

Comment: You must listen on all network interfaces, not just local host.

Comment: In the application.properties file i already specified server.address=0.0.0.0 if this is what you mean, as well with server.port=8091. I will update the question with this detail.

Comment: Does your application generate any logs, e.g. on stdout (`docker log -f your_container`)?

Comment: The main thing I figure out from instruction is docker run -p 8090:8091 lib_proj

you are mapping 8091 port with 8090. So you should use localhost:8090 not 8091. first port is your machine port second one is container port.

When you are using on browser you are using 8090. Please provide more logs for container to identify problem

Comment: Yes.  The thing that localhost inside docker is not localhost on the host confuses most people.    You can always install a program (telnet or netcat for instance) in the container, so you can try to connect from the inside to see how things are.

Comment: @KaranjotSingh well, the port 8091 is the one that my application is listening to, while 8090 is the port that I bind on my machine. If I run my application inside IntelliJ and I load localhost:8091 it works, while if I run it inside docker and I try to load localhost:8090, it doesn't work (and i am mapping the 8090 of my localhost with the 8091 of the container)

Comment: @tony please use bounties to attract attention to your problems.  That works much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a workaround I found is to leave all the port to the default 8080. So i replaced the 8091 in the dockerfile and the 8090 in the "docker run ..." command to 8080 and now it works here. I assume because tomcat behind the scene only listens to this one, and I'm figuring out how to change this.